# What does "@" do in Elixir?

Tags: syntax, elixir

I have been looking through some coding solutions and they show the "@" symbol; however, I can't really seem to figure out what that symbol does by looking through documentation.

What does the @ symbol do in Elixir, and why is it important?

Here is an example:

```
defmodule RNATranscription do
  @dna_nucleotide_to_rna_nucleotide_map %{
    # `G` -> `C`
    71 => 67,

    # `C` -> `G`
    67 => 71,

    # `T` -> `A`
    84 => 65,

    # `A` -> `U`
    65 => 85
  }

  @doc """
  Transcribes a character list representing DNA nucleotides to RNA

  ## Examples

  iex> RNATranscription.to_rna('ACTG')
  'UGAC'
  """
  @spec to_rna([char]) :: [char]
  def to_rna(dna) do
    dna
    |> Enum.map(&get_rna_for_dna/1)
  end

  defp get_rna_for_dna(dna_nucleotide) do
    @dna_nucleotide_to_rna_nucleotide_map[dna_nucleotide]
  end
end
```

Comment: What changed in the last two years to make you prefer the other answer? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@` symbol in Elixir denotes [module attributes](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html), which are useful compile-time settings.  You often see them in places where you might put class constants in an OO language.

However, module attributes are more subtle than what you might find in an OO language. Here are some important takeaways:

1. They do **not** use the `=` to assign a value (as you might be in the habit of doing if you are used to defining class constants in OO-land).  The syntax is more like `function input` where the optional parentheses are dropped.
2. Module attributes can be redefined multiple times throughout the module.  You'll see this frequently with `@doc` attributes that annotate the function that follows it, with `@spec` which annotates the function input/output, or inside tests with `@tag` to change the inputs to the test that follows it. This can offer a useful way to put big values out of the way of the function logic to improve readability.
3. Module attributes can be *accumulated*.  Normally, each instance of an attribute reassigns its value, but if you set [`accumulate: true`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#register_attribute/3) when you register the attribute, then subsequent definitions will accumulate so that reading the attribute will return *all* the accumulated values.  From the doc page:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  Module.register_attribute(__MODULE__, :custom_threshold_for_lib, accumulate: true)

  @custom_threshold_for_lib 10
  @custom_threshold_for_lib 20
  @custom_threshold_for_lib #=> [20, 10]
end
```

4. Module attributes are evaluated at **compile-time**.  Because they can raise visibility on important module-wide values, you might be tempted to do something like stash an ENV value:

```
defmodule Trouble do
  @my_value System.fetch_env("BOOM") # <-- don't do this!
end
```

More recent versions of Elixir will show warnings if you attempt to do this (and some values, e.g. captured functions, will raise an error), so as a general rule of thumb, it's best to keep the module attributes simple and static.

Answer (score 5):

It's the syntax for a [module attribute](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html):

> Module attributes in Elixir serve three purposes:
>
> 1. They serve to annotate the module, often with information to be used by the user or the VM.
> 2. They work as constants.
> 3. They work as a temporary module storage to be used during compilation.

Attributes are read by the compiler at compile-time, so they cannot be accessed or changed at runtime. At runtime, they will have been replaced with whatever was evaluated by the compiler.

In your case, this function:

```elixir
defp get_rna_for_dna(dna_nucleotide) do
  @dna_nucleotide_to_rna_nucleotide_map[dna_nucleotide]
end
```

Is effectively compiled to this:

```elixir
defp get_rna_for_dna(dna_nucleotide) do
  %{
    71 => 67,
    67 => 71,
    84 => 65,
    65 => 85
  }[dna_nucleotide]
end
```

`@spec` is used to define [typespecs](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html), `@doc` is for documentation.